# Marketing Cloud Push Notification Tracking

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush

In my company we are currently investigating possibilities to enable tracking in the mobile push SDK to see push opens but there is consent consideration - in case we want to have an individual level tracking - we should ask for additional consent.

So there are 2 questions:

1. Is it possible to enable tracking only for the users who gave this consent while for others opens will be empty?
2. Is it possible to implement opens to see it on the high level only, e.g. open rate for a push message but to not see it individually?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Opens are aggregated in the reports. You *could* dig into the database and figure out exactly which device opened a message and then figure out who owns the device, but it would be a rigorous process.

If you want an additional layer of consent then I would suggest asking for the consent on app install and holding the SDK's initialization until after the user has decided. Then configure the SDK with the `etAnalytics` (aka engagement analytics) toggled appropriately.

Store the user's response to use it on subsequent initializations of the App/SDK as initialization is `REQUIRED` in the application's onCreate().

Comment: Hi Bill, thank you very much for such a quick response!

In terms of the 2nd question, I was more wondering whether it was possible to enable opens via push SDK and to not collect the info on the individual level but rather "anonymously" gather opens and see only opens per push, would you know about smth like that?

Comment: The switch is simply on/off. You're either collecting open statistics or your not. The reports generated will be anonymous, of course, but if you wanted to dig in to see if a specific device opened a push, you could -- but it would be a set of queries you'd have to make with database access.